# How to do a GET query with a body using IntelliJ HTTP Client for Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, intellij-idea, httpclient

I have Elastic Search and Kibana installed and running.

I can do the tutorial search by pasting this into Kibana's dev console and running it ...

```
GET /bank/_search
{
  "query": { "match": { "address": "mill lane" } }
}
```

... and I get the correct results back from Elastic Search.

Now I want to do this same GET using the HTTP Client in IntelliJ ...

In IntelliJ, using the HTTP Client Plug In, I paste the same text into a 'scratch.http' file and click the green arrow to run the query, but it returns all results, they are not filtered.

That is, it doesn't appear to be including the `{ "query" ...}` part in the request.

How do I perform this GET in the IntelliJ HTTP Client plug in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question ... in IntelliJ's HTTP Client plug in, do this ...

```
POST /bank/_search
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "query": { "match": { "address": "mill lane" } }
}
```